# When the browser reload resources, if users do not force clear cache(eg. Ctrl + F5)

Tags: browser

1. There are no additional versions of the image links on the page.
2. Users do not force clear cache

Comment: Ummm... what exactly is your question?

Comment: @CharonX thanks for the reply
In short, browser cache expiration rules.
I found some answers, but still not very clear. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869800/how-long-are-files-usually-kept-in-a-browsers-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869800/how-long-are-files-usually-kept-in-a-browsers-cache)